Flutter Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'getInitialAppLink' Dynamic call of null. Receiver: Instance of 'AppLinks' Arguments: []
Getting this error -
Exception has occurred.
Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'getInitialAppLink'
Dynamic call of null.
Receiver: Instance of 'AppLinks'
Arguments: []
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 296:3       throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 893:3   defaultNoSuchMethod
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 63:17                 noSuchMethod
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 868:31  noSuchMethod
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 318:12  callNSM
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 329:25  _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 494:10  callMethod
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 498:5   dsend
packages/supabase_flutter/src/supabase_auth.dart 195:44                           _handleInitialUri
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                _async
packages/supabase_flutter/src/supabase_auth.dart 187:33                           [_handleInitialUri]
packages/supabase_flutter/src/supabase_auth.dart 148:11                           _startDeeplinkObserver
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                _async
packages/supabase_flutter/src/supabase_auth.dart 145:38                           [_startDeeplinkObserver]
packages/supabase_flutter/src/supabase_auth.dart 70:13                            initialize
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 163:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 847:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 876:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 652:5                                         [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 722:7                                         callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                  _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:7                <fn>

I upgraded Flutter to this -
webtoons % flutter --version
Flutter 3.22.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5dcb86f68f (12 days ago) • 2024-05-09 07:39:20 -0500
Engine • revision f6344b75dc
Tools • Dart 3.4.0 • DevTools 2.34.3

After this, I tried to run my app but getting this error -
Error_Screenshot
Before this upgrade, the app used to run without any issues. If I click on the continue button at the top of the debug bar, the app works fine. This error although should not be happening and I cannot figure out why.

can we see your full code main.dart? And do your app use AppLinks?

I figured it out. It was because my deep links were not configured properly.

cool bro. You can mark your question as [Closed]
